# Limitation of android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I have made a JQuery script creates a string with some data and pictures. It need to load 895 pictures.The 895 pictures are 11MB big together.
But for some reason I stops loading pictures after picture 475. When I click on the photo to show some more info then it loads the photo in the pop-up. But not on the main page. I tried to split the string to append in the HTML in 2. But nothing changed.

**EDIT**

Debug message when it try to load picuture 496:

> W/chromium: [WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(86)] file:///android_asset/www/assets/media/Memetic.png#-12#1

Comment: Yes I need to load al those pictures because I have a search bar at the top. So If they want they can search for it. The original size of 895 pictures where first 33MB so I compressed them to 11MB. Now it loads in like 1 sec.

Comment: The pictures are local on the device I don't use any server. See my edit at picture 496 I got this debug message in android studio

Comment: Ah, right. Ok, that changes things quite a lot. I'll delete my previous comments then as they don't apply when loading from local sources. We still need to see your code in order to help you, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  No problem. What code do you need? My Js code how it creates the strings to append?